# Menu bar pushes down the body, and links does not align correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I activate the menubar the whole body is pushed down.

I addition, one of the links is not getting pushed down to the others, but aligns itself with the logo.

How do you fix these two things?

**I couldn´t not get it on fiddle** to make it easier for you. Here is 
the link anyways, but the menu bar does not work there. Maybe it will 
work for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/28js95yp/

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
body {margin:0;}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.home{
 float:left;
     display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<a style="float:left" href="#home">Home</a>
 <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
<a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<p>
Minimize the width to get the menu bar. Click on the menu bar, and watch this being pushed down by that nasty navbar. How do you fix that and the misalignment of the logo and one of the links. 
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `!important` after you add `float:none;` in small screen  for the links

> **The cause is**: The home link remains floating left so the next link
>   will automatically moves next to it

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ...

  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none!important;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

}
```

And for the content you need to use `position:absolute;` on the menu to make it overlap the content and add `margin-top` to content `<p>` or `padding-top` to body to show it right after the menu bar

See result below:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.home {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none!important;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .content {
    margin-top: 60px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a style="float:left" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<p class="content">
  Minimize the width to get the menu bar. Click on the menu bar, and watch this being pushed down by that nasty navbar. How do you fix that and the misalignment of the logo and one of the links.
</p>
```

Comment: Amazing Chiller, thank you. That is amazing. There is the other half of what I also asked for:) When I open the menu bar, the content is pushed down. How do I fix that?

Comment: In addition, when I open the menu bar on my website it goes up. Here is my website, so you could have have a look. Hung.no (Minimize the window until you see the menu bar, and scroll down. Then click the menu bar)

Comment: @DuyTrinh I edited my answer... take a look its all fixed :)

Comment: Thank you very much Chiller. That is exactly what I asked for!

Answer (score 0):

Add this css to your menu :

```
{
position : absolute;
top : 0;
}
```